# I want to get the height from .xib file that I have created for customs cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 5 different types of custom cells. So I want to get different heights from the custom cells because I'm using these cells number of times based on my requirement. Is there any way to write a code which will calculate the height of .xib and will set the height of cell as the .xib height. And the height of cell should change based on the custom cell that I have choosen.

My question is similar to this question but I'm not getting the solution as they said here:

[Change tableview row height based on multiple cell xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349161/change-tableview-row-height-based-on-multiple-cell-xib)

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the custom table cell from xib, You need to subclass the tablecell method. You can use `awakeFromNib` to customize  your table cell!!!

To know the cell height, you need to over ride the layout subviews method, and you can get the cell height by the following code:

```
    self.frame.size.height
```

You can add an observer to the frame in the layout subviews method, so that you can get a notification, whenever there is a change in the height!!!!

**From Documentation**:

> Prepares the receiver for  service after it has been loaded from an
>   Interface Builder archive, or nib file. The nib-loading infrastructure
>   sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib
>   archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been
>   loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib
>   message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action
>   connections already established. You must call the super
>   implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity
>   to perform any additional initialization they require. Although the
>   default implementation of this method does nothing, many UIKit classes
>   provide non-empty implementations. You may call the super
>   implementation at any point during your own awakeFromNib method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not getting exact idea of how to do it in awakeFromNib can you please tell me the procedure ?

Comment: as u said, you want to know the height of the each custom cell, add an observer for frame change of the custom cell in the layout subviews method

Comment: I didn't get the exact answer. I'm poor in using xib , So where I have to write this "self.frame.size.height", and I have 5 tableViewCells so Do I have to subclass all of them in "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method ?